# Vue-router missing param when I go to the next route with dynamic name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

```
  <router-link
:to="{name: routeName, params: { place_id: place_id, name: name, term: term, logo: logo }}"
class="subscription" />
```

This is the code of my single file template. When I try go to the next route with dynamic name like 'subscriptions/:place_id'. I receive error "missing param for named route "subscriptions": Expected "place_id" to be defined"

```
  {
  path: '/subscriptions/:place_id',
  name: 'Subscriptions',
  component: Subscriptions,
  meta: {
    requiresAuth: true,
    shema: 'light'
  },
```

After render parent component (page "Subscriptions"), I try to get $route.params.place_id in mounted hook, but also receive "undefined" value in bug reporter. Please help Me, Why it happens.

Comment: you should provide more information. How you provide `place_id` to component?

Comment: Thanks, Already resolve it. I get it from 'place_id`s' from my datebase by JSON. The problem was in the next. When you have the sub children in component (route) "Subscriptions and <router-view/> in it, and then try to toggle sub-pages "Event.target button or link" should also provide this params. Other way you loose it, because "ROUTE.PARAM" become global variable and when you try go to another router-link you rewrite it.